# How add nestjs to a cloned nestjs project from github?

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs, node-modules

I clone the project from the repository's github, install nest/cli globally, and i try to run `nest generate module auth`, How can I make nest cli work in my project? And how to do it without extra nesting? Because in my case I have to create a Nest project and I clone repositories inside it, it turns out extra nesting

Answer (score 1):

I did all it again and I think I missed 1 step. It's `npm install`. And it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
cd <your folder>

nest new .
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?